# How to get the value from onPostExecute() to onCreate

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I declare a Global variable BigCLat and BigCLng like this :

public static String BigCLat;
public static String BigCLng;

and update values in onPostExecute.

when i try to setText in this method, its get the right value. But, its not update and null in onCreate.

Explain ::::
I need to set a value to my global variable(BigCLat, BigCLng) but its not update when i call in onCreate. –

Thank for answer.

......................

This is my onPostExecute.

```
public void onPostExecute(String result1) {

        BPlace_data = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            JSONObject jsonRoot = new JSONObject(result1);
            JSONArray jArray = jsonRoot.getJSONArray("results");

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                NearbyPlace nearbyPlace = new NearbyPlace();
                nearbyPlace.place_name = json_data.getString("name");
                nearbyPlace.vicinity = json_data.getString("vicinity");
                nearbyPlace.lat = json_data.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lat");
                nearbyPlace.lng = json_data.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lng");
                nearbyPlace.reference = json_data.getString("reference");

                BPlace_data.add(nearbyPlace);
            }

            BigCLat = BPlace_data.get(0).lat;
            BigCLng = BPlace_data.get(0).lng;

            TextView BigCLa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            BigCLa.setText(BigCLat);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following steps .

1 . Put following line inside onCreate()

```
BigCLa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
```

2 . Make BigCLa global .

3 . Remove following line from onPostExecute()

```
TextView BigCLa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
```

4 . Keep all other things as it was .

Now build code and check you should get the updated values on the screen .

Comment: Oh! I get the updated values. But i want to update BigCLat, BigCLng and setText at onCreate.

Comment: @user3712289 But i want to update BigCLat, BigCLng and setText at onCreate ? Please explain .

Comment: I need to set a value to my global variable(BigCLat, BigCLng) but its not update when i call in onCreate.

Comment: @user3712289 You can not access this value in onCreate() , since onPostExecute() calls later than onCreate()

Comment: @user3712289 Why do you want to access those variables in onCreate() ? Is there any specific requirement ?

Comment: I want those variables to find a distance from current location to  2 places and compare a distances to find the nearest place.

Comment: @user3712289 you can do that task just after getting lattitude and longitude in onPostExcecute() .

Comment: Now you can mark this answer as accepted , by choosing tick available at top-left corner  of the answer .

Answer (score 0):

Set `Textview BigCLa;` as global and use 
`BigCLa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);` 
inside `OnCreate` method.
Update `BigCla` value in `onPostExecute` Method as `BigCLa.setText(BigCLat);`